# Remove the space on <p> using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the text inside a bunch of `<p>` elements inside a `<div>`
This is what I have:

```
=importXML(C2,"//div[contains(@class,'article-body')]/p/text()")
```

The xpath works fine on Google Sheets and shows the text, but is creating a new row on Google Sheets for every `<p>` element ...Pieces of text on every row.

Is there a way to connect all the text inside all the `<p>` elements so at the end I just have one row with all the text on it?

Here is the source code:

```html
<div class="article-body" itemprop="articleBody">

  <p>Believe the buzz: <a href="/tvshows/the-people-v-o-j-simpson-american-crime-story/705835/"><em>The People v. O.J. Simpson: American Crime Story</em></a><em> i</em>s really good - like, edge-of-your-seat, a little bit outrageously good.</p>

  <p><strong>1. It's still an emotionally loaded story, 25 years later. </strong>While shooting the series, <a href="/celebrities/cuba-gooding-jr/213507/">Cuba Gooding Jr.</a>, who plays O.J. Simpson, was reunited with John Singleton, who not only directs
    an episode but is the only one among them who'd met and talked with O.J. "The first time I worked with ing."</p>

  <p><em>American Crime Story: The People v. O.J. Simpson</em> premieres Tuesday, Feb. 2 at 10/9c on FX.</p>
</div>
```

This is how it looks on Google's Chrome inspector:

```html
<div class="article-body" itemprop="articleBody">
::before
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p data-section="sharethrough"></p>
  <div data-placement="articles.show.sharethrough.inline" id="native_top" class="ad-dfp"></div>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
::after
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works - Part of the reason it was broken up is for two reasons - you were grabbing each p element instead of the whole blocks - and also saying for it to contain p when you can just grab the whole div like this:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.tvguide.com/news/the-people-vs-oj-simpson/","//*[@class='article-body']")
```

or if you want all the questions to be together in a single cell:

```
=concatenate(IMPORTXML("http://www.tvguide.com/news/the-people-vs-oj-simpson/","//*[@class='article-body']"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Aurielle it works... and also amazing you know I was using tvguide.com as my source, thanks again!!